# Load new dataset for each frame Processing

Tags: processing

I have a map of where publications (journal articles from pubmed) are from for a subject area. I want to do an anination in to show how the places publications come from changes every year. I have a data set of published article which has as one of its fie lds,the year of publication. I want the sketch to show a different years publications  with each frame (over 60 years). Is there a simple way to do this in Processing or do I have to create a series of year specific datasets. I'm looking for concept rather than code....

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to create a data structure that holds the article information, organized by year.

For example, you might create a class that encapsulates everything about an article, including the year. Then you might create an `ArrayList` that contains every article with a certain year- that `ArrayList` is now a year's worth of publications.

Expanding that, you'd create an `ArrayList` for **every** year, and then you'd store those `ArrayLists` inside another data structure- an array, or even another `ArrayList`.

Then to access the publications for a certain year, you'd just go into your data structure and look up the `ArrayList` for that year.

It's hard to be more specific without seeng an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're stuck on, but that's the general concept.